# End recording once silence is detected

Tags: scripting, audio

I've been using something like this up to now: [End sox recording once silence is detected](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55032/end-sox-recording-once-silence-is-detected)

But now I'd like for the audio source and recording mechanism to be separate.

I can get the source as an .m3u stream. It's a two-ray radio stream, and so there will be periods of inactivity.

I've been reading the documentation for sox and don't see something for using a stream as a audio device.

Is there a better tool for this?

Comment: Sox can read audio data from STDIN over a pipe. Just a pointer, not sure if that'll help... Or it can talk to PulseAudio, and you could do audio routing through PA.