# Can I record sound until silence OR a maximum length of recording?

Tags: audio, sox

Looking at [detecting sound until some silence occurs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55032/end-sox-recording-once-silence-is-detected), I arrived at the command `rec recording.flac rate 32k silence -l 1 0.1 3% 1 3.0 3%`.

I realize my specific use would be somewhat different: I do want to record until some silence is detected, but I also want an upper limit, say 10-15 seconds, of how long the recording will go on before moving on. I can just prepend a `timeout 15s` command, which would give me a maximum speech time of (15 seconds - leading silence, which will vary), but is there some way to tell sox I only need the first x seconds of a recording, which would give me a maximum speech time of 15 secs regardless of leading silence?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `trim` effect; e.g., `trim 0 15` will pass through only the first 15 seconds of audio. You can put it before or after `silence`:

- If before `silence`, that effect will only “hear” 15 seconds and possibly output less, if there was silence to be removed from that 15 seconds.
- If after `silence`, `trim` will “hear” the audio with silence already removed and stop after 15 seconds of non-silence.